# Fastest way of forming a list of words from a .txt file

Tags: python-3.x, performance, list, file, optimization

I'm doing a web scraping of an online dictionary based on a list of words. Here is part of the word list in a **.txt** file: ...Divulge, Inadvertent, Panegyric, Draconian, Hodgepodge...

I developed a code that works perfectly but goes so slowly when the word list gets longer. In my case, the word list has about 3000 words and the code will do scraping for each word. My code looks like:

```
file = open('word_list.txt', 'r') 
search_list = file.read().split(',')
file.close()

for x in tqdm(range(int(len(search_list)))):
    search = search_list[x]

    # (BeautifulSoup web scraping...)

    # (pandas organizes dataframe into .csv)
print ('Done!')
```

It seems like the 1st step takes a lot of time. Is there any way I can speed up the whole process?

Comment: Have a look at [Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python](https://github.com/JeffPaine/beautiful_idiomatic_python). Did you measure where you spend most of the time?

Comment: Try running your code through a profiler, to see which line in particular is taking up the most time. I personally use [rkern's line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) for python. Also look at the link strippenzieher provided- I was going to suggest the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try something like this:

Write a simple program to convert search_list into a dictionary.

```
file = open('word_list.txt', 'r') 
search_list = file.read().split(',')
file.close()

search_dict = {}
for i in range(len(search_list)):
    search_dict[i] = search_list[i]
print(search_dict)
```

This should print out the entire word list in dict format such as {1: a, 2: an, ...} on your console. Copy and paste this dict into a new file or hardcode(if you want to maintain it that way instead of running this every time at the start). Saves memory space and also faster as the words in dicts don't change, and can always be updated later on.

```
for x in tqdm(range(int(len(search_dict)))):
    search = search_dict.get(x)

    # (BeautifulSoup web scraping...)

    # (pandas organizes dataframe into .csv)
print ('Done!')
```

> So, what you get is a dict, instead of a list, which supports random access. And this should be working in O(1) I think.